# First Makefile Questions: No rule to make target

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, gnu-make

I'm attempting to create my first ever Makefile and looking for the most simple, understandable version--even if it isn't "good practice." I'll deal with that at a later time. :)

Basically, I just want to run `make` in the command line and have it execute the several g++ commands so I don't have to. For example, instead of entering the following (at top level dir) in the command line...

`$g++ -c ./src/RaspPi4Main.cpp -o ./src/RaspPi4Main.o`

`$g++ -c ./src/funcI2cCom/funcI2cCom.cpp -o ./src/funcI2cCom/funcI2cCom.o`

`$g++ -o ./bin/RaspPi4Main ./src/RaspPi4Main.o  ./src/funcI2cCom/funcI2cCom.o -lwiringPi`

...I'd like something similar to my attempt at a Makefile:

```
RaspPi4Main: RaspPi4Main.o funcI2cCom.o (and all header files? or not needed if added below?)
    g++ -o ./bin/RaspPi4Main ./src/RaspPi4Main.o  ./src/funcI2cCom/funcI2cCom.o -lwiringPi

RaspPi4Main.o: RaspPi4Main.cpp
    g++ -c ./src/RaspPi4Main.cpp -o ./src/RaspPi4Main.o

funcI2cCom.o: funcI2cCom.cpp funcI2cCom.h
    g++ -c ./src/funcI2cCom/funcI2cCom.cpp -o ./src/funcI2cCom/funcI2cCom.o
```

Hopefully, I'm close? Thanks!

Comment: The -o flag to gcc must match the target name. You promise to build `funcI2cCom.o` but your recipe generates `./src/funcI2cCom/funcI2cCom.o ` also, your command should start with `g++`, not `$g++`

Comment: Is there a question here?  If something is not working please provide (cut and paste) the command you entered and the error you got.  And, it's helpful to spend a few minutes learning how to use StackOverflow formatting: to format a block of code indent with 4 spaces rather than using backquotes on each individual line.  Thanks!

Comment: @Botje Ah, ```$``` was a typo, edited question to reflect. So, I should change all of the target names to match the -o destinations?

Comment: And your inputs too. An input should either be a path to a file that exists or there should be a target to generate it.

Comment: @MadScientist Updated formatting, thanks. The question: I received the error "No rule to make target RaspPi4Main" and searching lead to one of many, many possibilities. So, just looking to see if a more experienced person could identify my mistake, if a small fix.

Comment: @Botje One last clarification, are the "inputs" the items after the ":"? I've read them called dependencies? Thank you.

Comment: Please provide the exact command you typed and the exact error you got, in your question, using cut and paste rather than paraphrasing.  For example I don't see how you could get that particular error based on the information you've provided, so there must be something different.  For example, maybe instead of `make` you ran `make RaspPi4Main`?  And, what is the name of your makefile?

Comment: In a simple Makefile such as this, the dependencies are often also the inputs to the recipe. In more complex ones that is not always the case, and some dependencies will only be there to enforce correct ordering of targets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first step, you need to make sure your recipes produce their target and that inputs are either files or targets of other rules:

```
bin/RaspPi4Main: src/RaspPi4Main.o src/funcI2cCom/funcI2cCom.o 
    g++ -o bin/RaspPi4Main src/RaspPi4Main.o src/funcI2cCom/funcI2cCom.o -lwiringPi

src/RaspPi4Main.o: src/RaspPi4Main.cpp
    g++ -c src/RaspPi4Main.cpp -o src/RaspPi4Main.o

src/funcI2cCom/funcI2cCom.o: src/funcI2cCom/funcI2cCom.cpp src/funcI2cCom/funcI2cCom.h
    g++ -c src/funcI2cCom/funcI2cCom.cpp -o src/funcI2cCom/funcI2cCom.o
```

Note that this is quite verbose. You can shorten it quite significantly by making use of [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables). Concretely, `$@` is the name of the target, `$<` is the name of the first dependency, and `$^` are all dependencies:

```
bin/RaspPi4Main: src/RaspPi4Main.o src/funcI2cCom/funcI2cCom.o 
    g++ -o $@ $^ -lwiringPi

src/RaspPi4Main.o: src/RaspPi4Main.cpp
    g++ -c $< -o $@

src/funcI2cCom/funcI2cCom.o: src/funcI2cCom/funcI2cCom.cpp src/funcI2cCom/funcI2cCom.h
    g++ -c $< -o $@
```

Note that there's quite some repetition. Luckily, Make already knows how to compile a .cpp file into a .o file through [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Using-Implicit.html#Using-Implicit). Thus you can omit the recipes for these rules:

```
bin/RaspPi4Main: src/RaspPi4Main.o src/funcI2cCom/funcI2cCom.o 
    g++ -o $@ $^ -lwiringPi

src/RaspPi4Main.o: src/RaspPi4Main.cpp
src/funcI2cCom/funcI2cCom.o: src/funcI2cCom/funcI2cCom.cpp src/funcI2cCom/funcI2cCom.h
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! Adding the direct paths to all the targets and inputs fixed the issue. Yes, very verbose at first but improved clarity for my first makefile was what I was after; but thank you for including and showing how the automatic variables can simplify things in the future. Thanks again!